# where is showing conversation value

Tags: javascript

THis topic is abouton google add word (conversation)

Below is my conversation setup screenshot
http://nimb.ws/alycTQ

Below is my code that was putted on body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function GoogleFormTracker()
{
goog_snippet_vars = function() {
var w = window;
w.google_conversion_id = 949468534;
w.google_conversion_label = "9xLwCK7rm3IQ9vrexAM";
w.google_conversion_value = 1;
w.google_remarketing_only = false;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
goog_snippet_vars();
window.google_conversion_format = "3";
var opt = new Object();
opt.onload_callback = function() {
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
  window.location = url;
}
}
var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
conv_handler(opt);
}
}
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
 </script>
```

GoogleFormTracker()  fired on footer when site is load.
And also i verified my code on tag manager chrome addons(No error showing there).
but i don't know where to showing me how many time this function is  fired ?
let me know any mistake in my code or where is showing tracking value in add word (with screenshot and step by step).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In google add word account follow below step

> Tool->Attribution

In Attribution available you conversation value.

I hope u need like above

Answer (score 0):

"but i don't know where to showing me how many time this function is fired". Not entirely sure I understand, but perhaps you just need to put a `console.log('marco');` inside the function and view the browser console (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) to see how many times the function is called?

Comment: Yeah i alredy know function once fire when page is load, but i need tracking value where is showing in in google add word account?

Comment: @suresh I'm sorry but I don't understand.